# Why does WCF make extra calls?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, protocol-buffers

I have a client that makes a call to a WCF service.  When I make the first call to the service, there are 2 extra calls (visible via Fiddler).

The action of the first one is s:mustUnderstand

[image]

The second call is:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the extra calls are being made?  How to get rid of them, if possible?
Just for reference, the data being transported is serialized with Protocol Buffers library by Marc Gravell.

Comment: Minor note - you can shave an extra bit of bandwidth if you can enable MTOM on the transport

Comment: @Marc Gravell. At what point (size of payload wise) does MTOM become useful?  I assume it has no bearing on small payloads, correct?

Comment: sure; on small payloads you probably won't see much advantage (latency will be your main factor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra calls are used to set up secure communications and the security context. Read this link: http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/11/secure-conversation-with-wcf.html

Comment: Thanks.  I don't really care about the security in this context.  Am I getting this because I am using wsHttpBinding?

Comment: "wsHttpBinding" is the security.

Comment: That is at least part of it. `wsHttpBinding` does support the WS-* features, including WS-Security. `basicHttpBinding` does not, so would not include these extra calls. However, it is probably possible to disable those extra security parts of `wsHttpBinding`, however I forget what the actual configuration settings are. You can probably Google something like "wcf disable ws-security" and find some writeups.